# Mounting a Windows share as a folder with data persistance in Win7/XP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, windows-xp, network-share

I was wondering if anyone had figured out a good way of mounting a network share (`\\server\dir1\dir2`) to a folder (say `C:\folder1\folder2`) in such a way that when the share is disconnected the data remains. Offline Files doesn't seem to work well with mklink. I can't find a way that makes the data persistent. Also most of the methods for mounting a share to a folder feel clunky, so I'm looking for a better way to do that too.

Comment: It sounds a bit like you want to have your cake and eat it to. Offline Files (or some equivalent third party tool/service) is probably as good as it's going to get.

Answer (score 1):

Offline files is the method to do it when you have a local file server available at least some of the time. If you want more portability then you could go to the cloud.

Look at solutions from the ubiquitous Dropbox, the new and flashy Google Cloud Storage https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/pricingandterms and lastly Jungle Disk with sync folders https://www.jungledisk.com/

The downside of syncing files this way is that multiple people cannot be in the same file (ie: databases) but you would probably not take that kind of file offline in the first place.